# Why my RecyclerView with CardView can't set width to match parent?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

i am wanto show my RecyclerView inside CardView with list, one by one, but my RecyclerView or CardView i think, can't set width to match parent.

This is My Activity Layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
android:id="@+id/rexyclerview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
card_view:cardCornerGroup="5dp"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And This Is My CardView Layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/cardview"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
        >
        <!--
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            >
             <TextView
            android:layout_width="130sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tmpkode"
            android:textSize="11sp"
            android:maxLines="1"

            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="70sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tmpkode"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textSize="11sp"
            android:id="@+id/tmptgla"

            android:textAlignment="center"
            />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="50sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tmptgla"
                android:id="@+id/tmpnamaz"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="100sp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tmpnamaz"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"

                android:id="@+id/namasup"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="130sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/namasup"
                android:textSize="11dp"
                android:id="@+id/nopenawar"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
       <!-- </LinearLayout> -->
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

My Adapter :

```
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
        View Itemview = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(Itemview);
    }
```

My Activity :

```
setContentView(R.layout.approvalpersetujuan);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rexyclerview);
        data = new ArrayList<>();
        Prosesdataserver(0);
        gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 5);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
```

Comment: I think the layout manager in your recycler view is grid layout, can you show the code which sets the layout manager for your recycler view?

Comment: yes, i am using gridlayout, please wait a minute.

Comment: @ShashankUdupa i edit my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need grid layout manager you can try this out

```
gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 1);
```

Or you can go for a horizontal linear layout manager like so

```
layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
```

and set it to your recycler view

Comment: Yes, it work, thank you. so, the `gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, x);`   x is the row right?

Comment: It's column count, but if you're going to have column count as 1 you can just use a linear layout manager, like I've shown.

Comment: sure, Thank you sir.